# How to create a loop based on user input of float/integer vs string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, loops, input, integer

Brand new to coding and trying to figure out how to evaluate whether user input is a float or integer greater than 0, and if not continue to prompt them for a response until they give me a response that meets this criteria.

I've been able to come up with the following that helps me separate valid responses (a number > 0) from invalid responses (a string or number <= 0):

```
input = "How much money do you have?"
print input
money_1 = gets.chomp.to_f
  if money_1 > 0 
   puts "You have $#{money_1}."
  else
   puts "Please enter a valid amount"
   print input
end
```

What I can't figure out is how to turn this into a loop so that the user has to keep entering a response until they input a number greater than 0.

Any advice? Seems like it should be an obvious answer but I haven't found anything that works after a couple hours of digging around and trying things out.

I'd also love to know if there's an easier way than my workaround to evaluate if user input is a float or integer vs a string and then keep prompting them for a response until they give me a float or an integer. Issue is I need to convert their input to a float to be able to use it in an equation later in the code, which is why I came up with this workaround because I figured any string would be converted to 0 and I'm really only looking for numbers greater than 0, but if there's a better way I'd love to learn it!

Thanks!

Comment: If you found any of the answers useful, be sure to 'accept' the answer by clicking the corresponding 'grey tick' so it turns green.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop), something like this:

```
input = "How much money do you have?" 
puts input
money_1 = gets.to_f

loop do
  if money_1 > 0 
    puts "You have $#{"%.2f" % money_1}"
    break
  else
    puts "Please enter a valid amount",
         input
  end
  money_1 = gets.to_f
end
```

If you don't need the `money_1` variable again or outside of the loop, the following will suffice:

```
loop do
  puts "How much money do you have?" 
  money_1 = gets.to_f
  if money_1 > 0 
    puts "You have $#{"%.2f" % money_1}"
    break
  else
    puts "Please enter a valid amount"
  end
end
```

Comment: There's a bit of a problem with this as written; after the loop, `money_1` is out of scope and can't be used.

Comment: `break puts` seems quite weird to me. Wouldn't it be clearer to have two statements, `puts` then `break`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland re first comment: 'weird' ha, yes I think you might be right, I don't think I've ever seen it done anywhere like this so not sure why I did. re second comment: cool I will check out the answer you just posted, had no idea you could do it like that tbh.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the loop exit test at the end you don't need redundant statements preceding the loop.

```
begin
  puts "How much money do you have?" 
  money_1 = Float(gets) rescue 0
  puts money_1 > 0 ? "You have $#{"%.2f" % money_1}" : "Please enter a valid amount"
end until money_1 > 0
```

I've also reduced the `if puts ... else puts... end` to a single line.

Comment: Nice. just a typo `money1`

Comment: @sagarpandya82, thanks for the catch and compliment. Come to think about it, I wonder what the `1` in `money_1` refers to. I think I'd use something like `amount`.

Comment: Interestingly, [Matz dislikes this idiom and wishes he'd never included it in the language](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/6745). He has even stated he may remove it in the future, though personally I think that's not likely to happen.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways to address this. The more common approach would be to use `loop`, `until`, or `while`. I generally prefer `loop`, but `while` is a little bit simpler in this specific case:

```
input = "How much money do you have?"
print input
keep_going = true 
while keep_going
  money_1 = gets.chomp.to_f
  if money_1 > 0 
    puts "You have $#{money_1}."
    keep_going = false
  else
    puts "Please enter a valid amount"
  end
end
```

You also asked about other ways to recognize floats; with [`String#to_f`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-to_f), a string like "Hello" results in zero, same as "0" does; however, the [`Float()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Float) method will raise an exception if passed an inappropriate string:

```
"hello".to_f #=> 0.0
Float("Hello") #=> ArgumentError: invalid value for Float(): "hello"
```

Now, it'd be nice if there was a version of that method that returned `false` or `nil` for invalid input, instead of raising an exception, but even as it is now it provides an alternative way of writing your code:

```
puts "How much money do you have?"

begin
  money_1 = Float(gets) # \n at the end is ignored by Float()
rescue ArgumentError
  puts "Please enter a valid amount."
  retry
end

puts "You have $#{money_1}."
```

If there were a hypothetical `Float?()` method that returned false instead of raising an exception, you could write this:

```
puts "How much money do you have?"
until money_1 = Float?(gets)
  puts "Please enter a valid amount."
end
puts "You have $#{money_1}."
```

This would be much nicer, because raising and rescuing exceptions to handle pretty normal situations like bad user input is pretty bad form.

Comment: The OP's `money_1 = gets.chomp.to_f; if money_1 > 0 ...` serves two purposes. One is to treat zero or non-numeric values (e.g., `"cat"`) as invalid (as `"cat".to_f #=> 0.0`). The second purpose is to disregard negative floats. Your method deals with the first (better than `to_f`, as it will nix `"9lives"`, which `to_f` will happily convert to `9.0`, and will also accept `1.0e8 #=> 100000000.0`, as I think it should), but not with the second. It's a minor fix, of course.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use a while loop like so:

```
while (input = gets.chomp.to_f) <= 0
  puts "enter a valid input"
end
puts "you have $#{input}"
```

This uses inline variable assignment. The `input` variable is redefined each loop using a fresh `gets` call. By the time the loop ends you know you have a positive value.